# Javascript dropdown only works once

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a text area to the specific dog based on what the user chooses in the dropdown of breeds using a button. It works on the first click but then outputs one letter only and then undefined with dogList being undefined.

```
var breedList = ["Toy", "Hound", "Terrier", "Working", "Mixed", "Non-Sporting", "Herding"];
var dogList = [ "Affenpinscher", "Afghan Hound", "Airedale Terrier", "Akbash Dog", "Alaskan Husky", "American Eskimo Dog", "Australian Shepherd"];
onEvent("button1", "click", function( ) {
  setText("text_area1", filter(getText("dropdown1")).join("\n"));
});
function filter() {
  var filterList = [];
  var breed;
  for (var i = 0; i < breedList.length; i++) {
    breed = getText("dropdown1");
    if (breed == breedList[i]) {
      dogList = dogList[i];
      insertItem(filterList, 0, dogList);
    }
  }
  return filterList;
}
```

Comment: post it as a working snippet

Comment: You need to add relevant HTML so we can reproduce it, and `setText`, `getText`, and `insertText` aren't part of the regular javascript library. If you want to solve it yourself, use `console.log()` to print `dogList` at relevant rows in your code where it can go wrong.

Comment: `dogList = dogList[i];` - why are you replacing the entire array with only one instance in the array (string)?

Comment: Rickard pointed out the case